# Python prints escape keys while entering input when pressing the arrow keys on Terminal

Tags: python, shell, terminal, anaconda, arrow-keys

I made a simple Python 3 script which takes an input from the user. But while entering the input, if I press left arrow key, instead of going left it prints ^[[D . It happens with all arrow keys. But it doesn't happen in Terminal or Python Interactive Shell, it only happens when I run a Python script from Terminal and need to enter an input.

I use Ubuntu 19.10 and Anaconda distrubition which runs Python 3.7.

```
operation = input("Enter the expression: ")
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Import the `readline` package before using `input`

```
import readline
operation = input("Enter the expression: ")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/readline.html

> Settings made using this module affect the behaviour of both the
>   interpreter’s interactive prompt and the prompts offered by the
>   built-in input() function.

Importing it will be enough to activate input line editing (arrow keys will move the cursor around instead of printing ^[[D, etc.). Other functions in the readline module can be used to set up tab completion and a history file.

Comment: Is there another way rather than adding this line of code to every script I make?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. What you've seen with your script - printing ^[[D, etc. - is the default behaviour. The Terminal and Python Shell are using readline.

Comment: But you don't need to type it down yourself in Terminal and Python Shell. Can yo configure Python to automatically import readline when you run a script?